# Auto-ARIMA function in R giving odd results

Tags: r, time-series, data-modeling, forecasting

I have a day level dataset for 3 years,
I ran `auto.arima()` in R on it for simple time series forecasting and it gave me a `(2,1,2)` model. 
When I used this model to predict the variable for the next 1 year the plot became constant after a few days, which can't be correct

As I have a daily data for 3 years, and a frequency of 364 days, is ARIMA incapable of handling daily data with large frequencies?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Reproducible code would help.  You could also try `?msts` setting seasonal 2 periods of 7 (days per week) and 364 (days per year)

Comment: That's how arima works. It basically reacts to observation on t-2 (in your case) with coeficient below 1 which implies gradual diminishing to average value... And it it's on daily basis for several years, you just won't see anything but a straigth line on such scale.

Comment: See this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-to-find-patterns-and-identify-changes-in-them-in-time-series-with-r/63651#63651

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are trying to forecast too far into the future. 
The forecast for tomorrow is going to be accurate, but the forecast for the next day and the day after that are not going to be influenced much by the past data and they will therefore settle around some constant when trying to forecast too far into the future. "Too far into the future" probably means two or more time points.

Lets say you have data up until time point T+100, which you used to estimate your ARIMA(2,1,2) model. You can "forecast" the value for time T+1 by pretending you only have data until point T and use your ARIMA(2,1,2) model to forecast T+1. Then move ahead by one period in your data and pretend you only have data until time T+1 and "forecast" T+2. This way you can assess the forecasting accuracy of your ARIMA(2,1,2) model, for example by calculating the Mean Squared Error (MSE) of the "forecasts".

Comment: So if ARIMA isn't the best way to forecast this far into the future, what method do you suggest given that I need to make forecast for a one year time period ?

Comment: In case the data shows high levels of seasonality at a one year interval, you could consider a seasonal ARIMA, which includes the value T-S, when forecasting the value at time T (if S is the order of seasonality). 
In any other case, there is most probably no dependency between T and T+365, or in other words, you probably can't forecast one year ahead, with the tools I am familiar with..